# sending data from a search bar to a url

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am having trouble. So I need to get data from an api. I have a search bar and the user needs to input the search bar to look up a super hero api.

How would I get data from a search bar and put in my url all in a .click function.

```
var userInput;
var url;
var test;
//https://superheroapi.com/api/10215865526738981

$(document).ready(function () {
  // when the user types in the data and clicks the button
  $(btn1).click(function () {
    // this is where the search bar is
    userInput = document.getElementById('mySearch').innerHTML;
  });

  url = 'https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/10215865526738981/search/batman' + userInput;

  // here is where the api link in say type in batman 
  // and is should pop up with info  about batman and

  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var html = '';

    $.each(data.results, function (i, demo) {
      html += '<h2>' + demo.name + '</h2>';
      //html += "<h2>" + demo.biography.alter-egos + "</h2>";
      html += '<h2> Power Stats ' + demo.powerstats.combat + '</h2>';
      html += '<p> Connections ' + demo.connections.relatives + '</p>';
      html += '<p> appearance ' + demo.appearance.gender + '</p>';
      html += '<h2> Work ' + demo.work.base + '</h2>';
      html += ' Profile <img src ' + demo.image.url + '>';
    });

    $('#demo').html(html);
  });
}
```

---

```
<p>
  <input type="search" id="mySearch" name="mySearch">
  <button id="btn1">Search</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</p>
```

Comment: There are few issues, you are setting `url` and calling `getJSON` on document load, not on button click. This fires up your request to `url` before user even has chance to input something. You need to move that into the click handler. Also, `p` elements should not have other `p` elements inside them

Comment: Ok so I added that into the .click event but how does it show the api infomation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that works that you can use to compare with your code and make something out of it. I've used plain javascript and left comments what is going on  so that you can learn from it.

There were few wrong assumptions in original question.

- code was executing on page load and didn't wait for user input
- url was hardcoded to start with batman + what ever user wrote

Code below is not perfect, but it is close enough to original code and it should be easy to understand. I also opted not to use jQuery, but you should be able to use it if wanted. Just replace `getElementById` with jQuery selectors and replace `XMLHttpRequest` with `getJson`.

I hope this helps you move ahead with your problem and that you will be able to learn something new which could help you better understand javascript. Happy coding!

```js
var button = document.getElementById('btn1');
// when user clicks on button, we want to call function start search
button.addEventListener('click', startSearch);

function startSearch(event) {
  // when we are starting the search, we want to pick up the value
  // input field from user
  var userInputValue = document.getElementById('mySearch').value;
  // this is base API url on which we can add what user wanted
  var urlBase = 'https://www.superheroapi.com/api.php/10215865526738981/search/'
  // if user did not provide name in input, we want to stop executing
  if (userInputValue === null || userInputValue === '') return;
  // if we are still in this function, append what user typed onto urlBase
  var searchUrl = urlBase + userInputValue;
  // call function which actually executes the remote call 
  performSearch(searchUrl);
}

function performSearch(searchUrl) {
  // this could be jQuery getJSON if you so prefer
  // here it is vanila JS solution of how to get data via AJAX call
  var requestData = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // because AJAX is always async, we need to wait until file is loaded
  // once it is loaded we want to call function handleResults
  requestData.addEventListener('load', handleResults);
  requestData.open('GET', searchUrl);
  requestData.send();
}

function handleResults() {
  // once we get response, because we used vanilla JS, we got response
  // available in this context as "this.response", however it is type string
  // we need to take that string and parse it into JSON
  var responseJSON = JSON.parse(this.response);
  // if there is error, we didn't find any character
  if (responseJSON.error) console.log('Character not found');
  else {
    var html = '';
    responseJSON.results.forEach(function (result)  {
      html += '<h2>' + result.name + '</h2>';
      // html += "<h2>" + demo.biography.alter-egos + "</h2>";
      html += '<h2>Power Stats ' + result.powerstats.combat + '</h2>';
      html += '<p>Connections ' + result.connections.relatives + '</p>';
      html += '<p>Appearance ' + result.appearance.gender + '</p>';
      html += '<p>Work ' + result.work.base + '</p>';
      // html += ' Profile <img src ' + result.image.url + '>';
    })
    // this is bad thing to do, injecting html like that into DOM
    // but let's leave this lesson for later stage
    // so, let's take this html and drop it onto the page
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = html;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" id="mySearch" name="mySearch">
<button id="btn1">Search</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const value = document.getElementById('mySearch').value;
```

And then use this value in your api url.